# Python Kivy: Changing defaulttheme-0.png won't change final .apk design

Tags: android, python, apk, kivy, buildozer

When I change the defaulttheme-0.png of my Python Kivy installation, my App appears different when launching it as .py on Ubuntu. But if I now "convert" it to an .apk and run it on my mobile (Android 5.1.2) it appears as before, without the theme being changed.
What do I have to do, to tell kivy/buildozer to integrate the theme into the .apk?

What I tried:
- Normally running "sudo buildozer android debug"
- Deleting all files created by "sudo buildozer init" and calling that one again
- And of course I searched Google, but as I didn't found anything, I hope you can help me, because my App would be almost done after fixing that problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the theme in a local kivy installation, place the image in a folder named data/images in your app's directory (i.e. `./data/images/defaulttheme-0.png` from your app script).

Edit: it is also necessary to copy the atlas file to this location, as noted by Tshirtman.

Comment: It did not work (the try took so long, because I suddenly had several buildozer problems). I placed a working defaulttheme-0.png in a /data/images/ folder from my script. Do I add anything in my script itself?

Comment: Try copying the atlas file at the same place too, because atlas uses dirname on its own filename, it'll look for the textures in the same dir as itself, and since it's the atlas that resource_find is actually looking for, and you don't provide it, you'll get both original files, if you don't provide a copy of both.

Comment: Yep, that worked thank you :) Please update your solution up there, so I can accept it for you and others.