# How to set UI theme image in Python Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am writing a very simple app with Kivy on Windows that only consists of a bunch of toggle buttons and want to be able to customise the colours of all of them easily. It is a single python file at the moment and I would like to keep all the code in that one file if possible.

If I change the `defaulttheme-0.png` in my Kivy instalation folder (`C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\kivy\data\images`) my app uses the file and displays the colors as defined in the image.

**I would like to know how to make my app use another copy of the image for its theme without changing Kivy instalation.**

It's a very simple one-off app for communicating with an Arduino via serial and controlling a couple of relays. As far I have this much and all is working as I want up to this point:

```
import serial
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (400, 100)

class R(App):
  def build(self):
    def pstate(PBTN,state):
      # serial communication
      print("P "+PBTN.state)
      
    def lstate(LBTN,state):
      # serial communication
      print("L "+LBTN.state)  
      
    PBTN = ToggleButton(text = 'P',
                        font_size=20,
                        state='down')
    PBTN.bind(state=pstate)
    
    LBTN = ToggleButton(text = 'L',
                        font_size=20,
                        state='down')
    LBTN.bind(state=lstate)
    
    b = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
    b.add_widget(PBTN)
    b.add_widget(LBTN)
    return b
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    R().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried this myself, but the [kivy.resources documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.resources.html#customizing-kivy) says that you can accomplish what you want using [kivy.resources.resource_add_path](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.resources.html#kivy.resources.resource_add_path).

Actually, an easier approach is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002726/python-kivy-changing-defaulttheme-0-png-wont-change-final-apk-design). Just copy your new `defaulttheme-0.png` and the `defaulttheme.atas` into a `data/images` sub-folder of your app.